# Showing one article element and hiding others at the same time using JQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, article

I have three internal links on HTML page and when I click them they show an article element for a while, which has some text. Each link has a separate article element (and other article elements should be hidden, when that one is shown). The chosen article element must be shown for 2 seconds and hidden automatically after 3 seconds.

My problem is that no matter which link I click, it shows and hides all article elements, when it should show and then hide only the selected one, and keep others/non-clicked hidden all the time. How could I change this? Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("article").show(2000).hide(3000);
      $("article").siblings("article").hide();
  });
});




</script>
</head>

<body class="siblings">
 <a href="#Googlelink.1">Google Chrome</a> <br />
  <a href="#Mozillalink.2">Mozilla Firefox</a> <br />
  <a href="#Edgelink.3">Microsoft Edge</a> <br />

<article>
  <a href="#Googlelink.1"><h1>Google Chrome</h1></a><br />
  <p>Morbi eget urna lacinia, rutrum dolor ac, malesuada velit. Aliquam sit amet facilisis augue. 
  Pellentesque lorem purus, porttitor eget posuere sed, hendrerit a tortor. Suspendisse molestie leo sollicitudin ullamcorper commodo. In rhoncus hendrerit accumsan.
  Cras et leo nec diam volutpat egestas. Maecenas ac viverra dui. Aliquam nibh enim, lacinia sed ipsum sed, imperdiet sollicitudin dui. </p>
</article>

<article>
  <a href="#Mozillalink.2"><h1>Mozilla Firefox</h1></a><br />
  <p>Morbi eget urna lacinia, rutrum dolor ac, malesuada velit. Aliquam sit amet facilisis augue.
  Pellentesque lorem purus, porttitor eget posuere sed, hendrerit a tortor. Suspendisse molestie leo sollicitudin ullamcorper commodo.
  In rhoncus hendrerit accumsan. Cras et leo nec diam volutpat egestas. Maecenas ac viverra dui. Aliquam nibh enim, lacinia sed ipsum sed, imperdiet sollicitudin dui. </p>
</article>

<article>
  <a href="#Edgelink.3"><h1>Microsoft Edge</h1></a><br />
  <p>Microsoft Edge is a web browser developed by Microsoft. It was first released for Windows 10 and Xbox One in 2015, then for Android and iOS in 2017,[8][9] and macOS in 2019.[10]

Edge includes integration with Cortana and has extensions hosted on the Microsoft Store. Unlike Internet Explorer, Edge does not support the legacy ActiveX and BHO technologies.  </p>
</article>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all articles and show the one with matching href, using the href attribute of the clicked anchor element:

```
$("article").hide();
$("a").click(function(){
   href=$(this).attr('href');
   $("article a").each(function(i,e){
    if($(this).attr('href')==href){
     $(this).parent().show(2000).hide(3000); 
    }
   })
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("article").hide();
  $("a").click(function(){
   href=$(this).attr('href');
   $("article a").each(function(i,e){
    if($(this).attr('href')==href){
     $(this).parent().show(2000).hide(3000); 
    }
   })

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="siblings">
 <a href="#Googlelink.1">Google Chrome</a> <br />
  <a href="#Mozillalink.2">Mozilla Firefox</a> <br />
  <a href="#Edgelink.3">Microsoft Edge</a> <br />

<article>
  <a href="#Googlelink.1"><h1>Google Chrome</h1></a><br />
  <p>Morbi eget urna lacinia, rutrum dolor ac, malesuada velit. Aliquam sit amet facilisis augue. 
  Pellentesque lorem purus, porttitor eget posuere sed, hendrerit a tortor. Suspendisse molestie leo sollicitudin ullamcorper commodo. In rhoncus hendrerit accumsan.
  Cras et leo nec diam volutpat egestas. Maecenas ac viverra dui. Aliquam nibh enim, lacinia sed ipsum sed, imperdiet sollicitudin dui. </p>
</article>

<article>
  <a href="#Mozillalink.2"><h1>Mozilla Firefox</h1></a><br />
  <p>Morbi eget urna lacinia, rutrum dolor ac, malesuada velit. Aliquam sit amet facilisis augue.
  Pellentesque lorem purus, porttitor eget posuere sed, hendrerit a tortor. Suspendisse molestie leo sollicitudin ullamcorper commodo.
  In rhoncus hendrerit accumsan. Cras et leo nec diam volutpat egestas. Maecenas ac viverra dui. Aliquam nibh enim, lacinia sed ipsum sed, imperdiet sollicitudin dui. </p>
</article>

<article>
  <a href="#Edgelink.3"><h1>Microsoft Edge</h1></a><br />
  <p>Microsoft Edge is a web browser developed by Microsoft. It was first released for Windows 10 and Xbox One in 2015, then for Android and iOS in 2017,[8][9] and macOS in 2019.[10]

Edge includes integration with Cortana and has extensions hosted on the Microsoft Store. Unlike Internet Explorer, Edge does not support the legacy ActiveX and BHO technologies.  </p>
</article>


</body>
```

or even shorter:

```js
$("article").hide();
$("a").click(function() {
  href = $(this).attr('href');
  $("article a[href='" + href + "']").parent().show(2000).hide(3000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#Googlelink.1">Google Chrome</a> <br />
<a href="#Mozillalink.2">Mozilla Firefox</a> <br />
<a href="#Edgelink.3">Microsoft Edge</a> <br />

<article>
  <a href="#Googlelink.1">
    <h1>Google Chrome</h1>
  </a><br />
  <p>Morbi eget urna lacinia, rutrum dolor ac, malesuada velit. Aliquam sit amet facilisis augue. Pellentesque lorem purus, porttitor eget posuere sed, hendrerit a tortor. Suspendisse molestie leo sollicitudin ullamcorper commodo. In rhoncus hendrerit accumsan.
    Cras et leo nec diam volutpat egestas. Maecenas ac viverra dui. Aliquam nibh enim, lacinia sed ipsum sed, imperdiet sollicitudin dui. </p>
</article>

<article>
  <a href="#Mozillalink.2">
    <h1>Mozilla Firefox</h1>
  </a><br />
  <p>Morbi eget urna lacinia, rutrum dolor ac, malesuada velit. Aliquam sit amet facilisis augue. Pellentesque lorem purus, porttitor eget posuere sed, hendrerit a tortor. Suspendisse molestie leo sollicitudin ullamcorper commodo. In rhoncus hendrerit accumsan.
    Cras et leo nec diam volutpat egestas. Maecenas ac viverra dui. Aliquam nibh enim, lacinia sed ipsum sed, imperdiet sollicitudin dui. </p>
</article>

<article>
  <a href="#Edgelink.3">
    <h1>Microsoft Edge</h1>
  </a><br />
  <p>Microsoft Edge is a web browser developed by Microsoft. It was first released for Windows 10 and Xbox One in 2015, then for Android and iOS in 2017,[8][9] and macOS in 2019.[10] Edge includes integration with Cortana and has extensions hosted on the
    Microsoft Store. Unlike Internet Explorer, Edge does not support the legacy ActiveX and BHO technologies. </p>
</article>
```

```
$("article").hide();
$("a").click(function() {
  href = $(this).attr('href');
  $("article a[href='" + href + "']").parent().show(2000).hide(3000);
})
```